# почему-то не работает round

Tags: sql, postgresql

Подскажите, почему не получается округлить

```
SELECT distinct j.job_title,
 round((SUM(j.salary) / COUNT(distinct j.people_id)),2) as average_salary,
  COUNT(p.id) as total_people,
  round(SUM(j.salary),2) as total_salary


                   job_title|   average_salary| total_people|   total_salary|
                   advocate |       0.9703E2|             1|        0.9703E2|
```

Comment: а что не работает? Просили округлить до двух знаков после запятой - так и сделано. `0.9703E2` в десятичной записи и будет `97.03`. Интересно конечно почему ваш клиент выбирает показывать в экспоненциальном формате

Comment: а как перевести из экспоненциального формата в обычный, это задание к codewars, я просто обучаюсь

Comment: `round(x, dp)` - возвращаемый тип `numeric`, т..е никакой не экспоненциальный. Тот клиент, что ты используешь, зачем-то отображает в экспоненциальной форме. Максимум, что тут можно сделать (кроме смены клиента), самому переводить в строковую форму

Answer (score -1):

добавил ::float  после скобок общих и сработало